# Reemplazo de Y por E seguida de coma

Tags: puntuación, conjunciones

¿Es correcto reemplazar *y* por *e* cuando la siguiente palabra (que comienza con *i*) esta dentro de una una aclaración entre comas?

Ejemplo:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo e, inevitablemente, fallé.

Dentro de mis pocos conocimientos técnicos, entiendo que *inevitablemente* actúa como aclaración, y dudo si se aplica la regla tal cual y tengo que reemplazar *y* por *e* o si aplico la regla que se corresponda al caso sin la aclaración entre comas.

Espero haber logrado explicarme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Con el riesgo de estar equivocado pues no he logrado encontrar una regla o explicación que diga lo contrario.

La idea de reemplazar la "y" por "e" cuando la siguiente palabra comienza con "i" es para no tener dos sonidos iguales uno después del otro y que no se produzca una interrupción.

En francés hay reglas similares en donde se sustituye la última vocal de la palabra por un apóstrofe cuando la siguiente palabra comienza por vocal para ligar ambas palabras y que el lenguaje sea más fluido.

Debido a esto es mi opinión, salvo que alguien encuentre una regla que indique lo contrario, que el hecho de que haya una coma entre las dos palabras "y" e "inevitable" es irrelevante y la "y" debe sustituirse por "e".

**Aclaración**

Con base en tu comentario, creo que ya entiendo tu confusión.

Lo que entiendo es que la oración original era:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo y fallé.

La pregunta es que si al hacer la aclaración la oración debería de cambiar a:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo e, invariablemente, fallé.

La respuesta es un rotundo si. En la oración original no existe la cacofonía por lo que se usa la "y", al agregar la aclaración se introduce la cacofonía por lo que la "y" debe cambiarse por "e".

Comment: Sí, también creo que sea un aclaración o inciso no importa, el hecho es que al leerlo no provoque una cacofonía.

Answer (score -3):

Cuando la construcción verbal tiene una explicación entre comas, si prescindes de lo que está entre comas la oración debiera seguir teniendo sentido. En el presente caso si escribes:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo e, inevitablemente, fallé.

cuando prescindes de la explicación la oración queda mal formada. En caso de usar la **y** antes de la explicación tambien, de manera evidente, queda mal formada la oración.

No conozco si exista alguna norma al respecto, pero mi sentido común me dice que estas construcciones deben (y pueden evitarse) En este caso tenemos formas de redactarlo y quedaría mucho mejor:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo y, sin poder evitarlo, fallé.

o también

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo y, de manera inevitable, fallé.

Esto explica solo para este caso aunque en general nuestra lengua tiene tantos sinónimos que evitar construir frases de una u otra forma siempre es posible. El evitar construir este tipo de frases lo veo óptimo para la forma escrita, no tanto, para la forma oral en la que decir:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo e, inevitablemente, fallé.

Es casi imperceptible, aunque ojo, cuando dices ****e ine****vitablemente. Suena un poco mal!!!

Otra razón que se me ocurre es que, en cuanto a la sonoridad de una oración, antes de hacer una pausa (como es el caso cuando vas a decir una explicación entre comas) es que es mucho más conveniente usar un sonido débil como la **y**, que un sonido de vocal fuerte como la **e**.

Comment: ¿Por que el menos uno? ¿Que discrepancia hay con lo dicho?