# ¿Cuándo se sustituye la conjunción "y" por "e"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, conjunciones

La conjunción copulativa *y* se sustituye por *e* ante palabras que empiezan por el sonido */i/*:

> Eres único e irrepetible

Sin embargo, el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas indica [algunas excepciones](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=9n8R9ghyFD6fcqFIBx):

> a) Cuando al sonido */i/* le sigue una vocal con la que forma
>   diptongo: *La mesa es de madera y hierro* (no <s>*de madera e
>   hierro*</s>).
>
> b) Cuando la conjunción se hace tónica y adquiere un valor adverbial
>   en oraciones interrogativas: *¿Y Inés?* [= *¿Dónde está Inés?*].

Además, [leímos en este mismo sitio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3019/1674) que cuando la conjunción precede una coma, también se mantiene la *y* pues su objetivo final de evitar cacofonías se mantiene:

> Quise hacerlo de tal modo e, inevitablemente, fallé.

Sin embargo, hay dudas que aún me quedan sin resolver:

- ¿Cuál es el criterio cuando la conjunción precede a un extranjerismo?

> (En un barco) A lo lejos se ven unas olas. E (¿Y?) icebergs también.

- ¿Cuál es el criterio con palabras extranjeras?

> ¿Cómo se dice "toddler" en castellano? ¿E (¿Y?) "infant"?

- ¿Cuál es criterio con palabras extranjeras que no empiezan por i pero cuyo sonido sí lo es?

> Las compañías aéreas que vuelan a mi ciudad son Iberia y (¿e?) Easyjet.

Comment: Sería genial poder tener una respuesta que cubriera todas las casuísticas.

Comment: Pues en las [entradas para _y_ en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c8HoARq|c8HrfrV|c8IFPyp) no aparece ese uso adverbial. [Según parece](http://www.rae.es/consultas/cambio-de-la-y-copulativa-en-e), esa _y_ sustituye a "_dónde está_" o "_qué tal_". En el ejemplo de _¿E (¿Y?) "infant"?_ sustituye a "cómo se dice". Se podría considerar un caso más de _y_ tónica (creo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que dice la Ortografía en su edición de 2010 ([página 77](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=gGBtCrliHKzyWUDJ)) es lo siguiente:

> [...] este fenómeno se produce por razones fónicas, no gráficas, de forma que lo determinante no es la grafía, sino el sonido que sigue a la conjunción. Por tanto, la *y* copulativa se transformará en *e* ante toda palabra que comience oralmente por /i/, aunque, por tratarse de un extranjerismo, no se escriba con *i-* o *hi-*: *Iberia e Easyjet*, pues la palabra inglesa *easy* se pronuncia con /i/ inicial. Paralelamente, debe mantenerse la *y* copulativa si la palabra que sigue no comienza oralmente con /i/, aunque gráficamente se escriba con *i-* o *hi-*: *el encuentro entre Franco y Hitler*, ya que en el nombre alemán *Hitler* la *h-* no es muda, sino aspirada.

A partir de aquí, podemos establecer lo siguiente:

- Si se trata de un extranjerismo incluido en el DRAE, como es el caso de *iceberg*, es buena idea consultar cómo se pronuncia la palabra. Así, el DPD [dice](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=iceberg) que la pronunciación es [izebérg] en España. Por tanto, como la palabra comienza oralmente por /i/, la *y* copulativa se transforma en *e*. Sin embargo, también dice que en el español de América está consolidada la pronunciación [áisberg]. En este caso no se debería cambiar la *y*. Se da entonces la circunstancia de que según el público objetivo del texto, el escritor puede decidir usar *y* o *e*.
- Si se trata de una palabra extranjera, se aplica lo mismo: dependerá de cómo se pronuncie la palabra. Como verás, la ortografía pone precisamente el ejemplo de *Iberia e Easyjet*. En el caso de *infant*, comprobamos en el traductor de Google que se pronuncia /ˈinfənt/, es decir, con sonido /i/ inicial, luego hay que cambiar la *y* por *e*. Esto mismo valdría para el caso de marcas comerciales, en las que el dueño de la marca decide cómo se pronuncia: *Android y iPhone*, ya que esta última se pronuncia [áifon].
- Como última opción, ¿qué pasa cuando se trata de un extranjerismo cuya pronunciación se desconoce? En este caso, te puedo poner como ejemplo un caso que se me dio hace muchos años, cuando hacía traducciones de [mangas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OBSM3PH%7COBSjmj4%7COBTib4V). En uno de ellos había dos personajes llamados Madoka y Hikaru. En japonés no existe un alfabeto, sino silabarios, y lo que vemos escrito en alfabeto es una *romanización* (transcripción a letras romanas) de la palabra. En estas transcripciones, las grafías *h* se deben aspirar, y por eso escribo *Madoka y Hikaru*. Sin embargo, vi escrito en muchos sitios *Madoka e Hikaru*, porque el que lo escribió entendía que la h- del segundo nombre era muda. Resumiendo: si no se conoce la pronunciación de la segunda palabra, imagino que es cuestión de jugársela si no tienes a mano a alguien que te asesore. El caso es que la regla está clara: es una cuestión de conocer el sonido que va detrás de la conjunción.

Comment: El caso de *iceberg* es especialmente problemático porque en España se pronuncia [izebérg] mientras que en otras zonas es [áisberg]. La elección de *y* o *e* dependerá de la variedad de castellano que hable el escritor o el público al que vaya dirigido.

Comment: @Yay curioso. Actualizo la respuesta para reflejar esto.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo el mismo DPD que citas dice que la pronunciación en toda América es [áisberg]

Comment: @rsanchez tenéis razón, es culpa mía, leí hasta _la grafía inglesa se pronuncia a la española: [izebérg] o, en zonas de seseo, [isebérg]_, y ahí dejé de leer. Vuelvo a modificar la respuesta.

Comment: Pido disculpas por cómo me he columpiado con el tema del iceberg. Las prisas nunca son buenas consejeras.

Comment: ¡Faltaría más hombre! La verdad es que el tema de los extranjerismos y, sobre todo, las palabras extranjeras trae mucha cola. Por ejemplo, los grupos de  música en España los pronunciamos castellanizados (/radiojed/) mientras que en América suelen pronunciarlos en inglés (/reidiojed/).

Comment: @fedorqui en España somos muy de dejar las cosas a medias: ni [guait leibel] ni [güite label], sino [guait label]. :) (Sí, hablo del [güisqui](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrwSGNr).)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¿Qué dejamos a medias en el güisqui?