# ¿Por qué decimos "emoticono" en lugar de "emocicono", si viene de emoción + icono?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico, jerga-internet, préstamo-lingüístico

En la jerga de internet se habla mucho de los [*emoticonos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EjqioHD). El DRAE ya lo contempla y lo define como:

> **emoticono**
>   *Del ingl. emoticon, y este de emotion 'emoción' y icon 'icono', infl. en su t. por icono.*
>   1. m. Inform. Representación de una expresión facial que se utiliza en mensajes electrónicos para aludir al estado de ánimo del remitente.

Sin embargo, como veis viene de *emotion* y *icon* <sub>(al ser un extranjerismo que se pronuncia /aicon/, usamos *y* y no *e* [fuente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17538/1674))</sub>.

Entonces me pregunto: ¿por qué al traducir el concepto no se tiró más hacia atrás en su etimología y se cogió la palabra española *emoción*, tan parecida, en lugar de tomar la inglesa *emotion* para formar la palabra? ¿Se trata de un caso de [*cronología relativa*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17690/1674)?

Comment: Y más aún: si en América Latina se usa mayoritariamente la forma esdrújula _ícono_ (al menos, [según el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=%C3%ADcono)), ¿por qué no "emocícono"?

Comment: ¿y porque se debería tirar más hacia atrás en su etimología? Es una palabra nueva y viene de una que los angloparlantes ya tenían. _Emoticon_ en inglés se vuelve simplemente en _Emoticon**o**_ Y a propósito de una pregunta reciente sobre "shortened words" ellos ahora prefieren _emoji_

Comment: @DGaleano sí, pero mi punto es: ¿por qué se adapta _icon_ a _icono_ y no _emotion_ a _emoción_?

Comment: Creo porque no se adaptaron dos palabras y se juntaron sino que se adaptó una que ya estaba formada.

Comment: @DGaleano eso parece lo explicación más razonable, pero me parece raro que no se adaptara "un poco más", máxime cuando la etimología es tan evidente y reciente.

Comment: Por tirar hacia atrás, se podría tirar hasta el latín *emotio*, de donde tenemos *emo**t**ivo*. De hecho, es probable que el que palabras derivadas de *emoción* (y en último término de *mover*) contengan esa *t* (*motor*, *motivo*, etc.) haya influido sobre la formación de la palabra *emoticono* tanto como la etimología inglesa.

Comment: Estaría muy chistoso si usaramos **"Emocicón"**: Me enviaron un emocicón por el mensajero. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La castellanización de las locuciones de otros idiomas, en general, trata de normalizar de manera escrita la pronunciación original. No es, por lo tanto, necesario hacer un análisis etimológico. Entonces, debido a que el vocablo se pronuncia en la jerga como [ɪˈməʊtɪkɒn](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/emoticon) y del hecho que emotivo e ícono son dos palabras comunes del español, la castellanización mas natural sería *emoti + ícono* que resulta en dos posibilidades: **emotícono**, **emoticono**. En el DRAE, el vocablo normalizado es [emoticono](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EjqioHD).

Por otro lado, sería demasiado rebuscado recurrir a un análisis etimológico pare esto. Entonces, es preferible normalizar una pronunciación que ya se utiliza que cambiarla por el solo hecho de buscar una consistencia. Al fin y al cabo, hay múltiples inconsistencias en el idioma español.

Por último, si bien es cierto que la palabra **emoticon** proviene de manera inmediata del inglés; emotion (en inglés) y emoción(en español) se derivan, a su vez, del latin *motio* que significa movimiento. En español, la *t* se convierte en *c* dependiendo de la pronunciación como en *emoción* a diferencia de *emotivo*. Esta alteración no ocurre en inglés donde la *t* no cambia pero si la pronunciación: **Emotion ([əˈmōSH(ə)n](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/definicion/ingles_americano/emotion))**; **Emotive ([əˈmōdiv](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/definicion/ingles_americano/emotive))**.