# ¿Debe sustituirse "y" por "e" si la palabra empezada por "i" viene tras una coma y dentro de una frase secundaria?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, conjunciones, vocales

Supongamos esta frase:

> Me gusta el fútbol **y, independientemente** de la competición, miro todos los partidos de mi equipo.

Dicho en voz alta se oye un sonido /y/ redundante que hace que uno piense en cambiarlo por *e* tal y como se comenta en [¿Cuándo se sustituye la conjunción "y" por "e"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17537/1674).

Sin embargo, a mí siempre me enseñaron que las frases entre comas deben tratarse como si no existieran. Es decir, que si las omitimos la frase tenga sentido igualmente. En este caso, sería:

> Me gusta el fútbol **y** miro todos los partidos de mi equipo.

En cuyo caso un *e* en lugar de *y* sería extrañísimo.

Lo mismo estoy mezclando churras con merinas, ¿pero debe cambiarse la *y* por *e* en este caso?

Comment: Me suena mejor con e y las comas se pueden omitir. :)

Comment: Entiendo que sí. Fíjate que este ejemplo de la otra pregunta es muy similar: *Quise hacerlo de tal modo e, inevitablemente, fallé.*

Comment: Yo lo haría con "y" y una buena pausa.

Answer (score 1):

No me suena bien con `y`, mejor con `e`, otra cosa es que creo que la coma está mal puesta. De hecho `y,` apenas lo he visto por no decir nunca, `, y` lo he visto poco pero al menos soy consciente de haberlo visto

Comment: fíjate que no estoy poniendo `, y` sino `y,`. Es decir, la coma va _después_ de la _y_.